# Remove entire rows with missing values c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I am reading the data with different variables by the following codes, currently when the program touches missing values (represented in data by string "NA", it will change them to zero. Alternatively, I wonder if how can we remove entire rows when program touch "NA". I have tried to look for the same question but they all are for R, not C++. Please, if you can give me some advises. Thanks

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>
 using namespace std;

struct Data {
vector<double> cow_id;
vector<double> age_obs;
vector<double> dim_obs;
vector<double> my_obs;
vector<double> mcf_obs;
vector<double> mcp_obs;
vector<double> mcl_obs;
vector<double> bw_obs;
vector<double> bcs_obs;
double get_number (string value)
 {
   if (value == "NA")
    {return 0.0;}
   else
    {
    istringstream iss (value);
    double val;
    iss>>val;
    return val;
    }
 }
void read_input (const string filepath)

{
ifstream data_in (filepath.c_str());
if (!data_in)
{cout<<"Failed to open"<<endl;}
else
{
  // Read tokens as strings.
  string id, age, dim, my, mcf, mcp, mcl, bw, bcs;
  string dummy_line;
  getline(data_in, dummy_line);
  string line;

  while (data_in >> id >> age >> dim >> my >> mcf >> mcp >> mcl >> bw  >>    bcs)
  {
     // Get the number from the string and add to the vectors.
     cow_id.push_back(get_number(id));
     age_obs.push_back(get_number(age));
     dim_obs.push_back(get_number(dim));
     my_obs.push_back(get_number(my));
     mcf_obs.push_back(get_number(mcf));
     mcp_obs.push_back(get_number(mcp));
     mcl_obs.push_back(get_number(mcl));
     bw_obs.push_back(get_number(bw));
     bcs_obs.push_back(get_number(bcs));

  }
  data_in.close();
 }

size_t size=age_obs.size();
for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
{
  cout<<cow_id[i]<<'\t'<<age_obs[i]<<'\t'<<dim_obs[i]<<'\t'<<my_obs[i] <<'\t'<<mcf_obs[i]<<'\t'<<mcp_obs[i]<<'\t'<<mcl_obs[i]<<'\t'<<bw_obs[i] <<'\t'<<bcs_obs[i]<<endl;
}
};


int main()
{
Data input;
input.read_input("C:\\Data\\C++\\learncpp\\data.txt");

}
```

Comment: It's time to just give up and dump all my rep into bounties. Peace out SO!

Comment: @Captain: cannot get your points?

Comment: @hieu _"Please, if you can give me some advises."_ Sure. Step through your code line by line with the debugger, set breakpoints of interest, inspect variable values.

Comment: @hieu: I recommend a change in design:  instead of many vectors, place these fields into a `struct` or `class` and then have a `std::vector` of that class/struct.

Comment: Why is *everything* in one class?  In C++ you can have functions outside of a class, look at `main` as an example.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for your recommendation, I am doing it now. 
I am just a newbie to C++, and this is one of my first programs so please forgive me if questions are stupid. I hope to get your help. Thanks

Comment: By the way, a quick count says you're missing a `}` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's talk tables here.

Tables are containers of records (rows).  The data you are capturing from your input file is already organized into records.  So the obvious model is to use a structure that matches your file's data records.

```
struct Record
{
  unsigned int cow_id;
  unsigned int age_obs;
  unsigned int dim_obs;
  // ...
};
```

Your table could be represented as:

```
std::vector<record> my_table;
```

So to remove a record from the table, you can use the `std::vector::erase()` method.  Easy.  Also, you can use the `std::find()` function to search the table.

Let's relieve some reader's headaches with your present code by introducing a concept of the record loading its members from the file.

Reading a record from a file is best performed by overloading the stream extraction `operator>>`:

```
struct Record
{
  //...
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
  std::string record_text;
  std::getline(input, record_text);
  // Extract a field from the record text and check for NA,
  // Assign fields of r to those values:
  r.cow_id = value;
  // Etc.
  return input;
}
```

With the overloaded operator, your input looks like:

```
Record r;
while (input_file >> r)
{
  table.push_back(r);
}
```

Elegant and simple (reducing injection of defects).

Comment: highly appreciate your efforts, I am studying your new codes line by line.